# How to engineer/preprocess features for the input layer of a exported tensorflow 2.0 keras model for tensorflow serving

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.0, feature-engineering

I have created a model using TensorFlow-2.0-beta1. This uses the Keras functional API to perform regression on the input data. The data needs to have the categorical features one-hot encoded and the numeric inputs normalized. In the past using the Estimators API in TF1.11 this could be fixed using the feature columns and applying engineering to the feature in the ServingInputReceiver. Is there a way to do something similar when exporting a model from keras?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import pandas as pd

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()  # For easy reset of notebook state.

VERSION = tf.__version__
CWD = os.getcwd()
PARENT_DIR = os.path.split(CWD)[0]
DATETIME = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(PARENT_DIR, 'data')
train_file_path = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'traindf.csv')
test_file_path = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'testdf.csv')

CATEGORIES = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "CATEGORIES")
fileObject = open(CATEGORIES, 'rb')
CATEGORIES = pickle.load(fileObject)
fileObject.close()

NUMERICSTATS = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "NUMERICSTATS")
fileObject = open(NUMERICSTATS, 'rb')
NUMERICSTATS = pickle.load(fileObject)
fileObject.close()


# CSV columns in the input file.
with open(train_file_path, 'r') as f:
    names_row = f.readline()

CSV_COLUMNS = names_row.rstrip('\n').split(',')
print(CSV_COLUMNS)


drop_columns = ['SubSilo','Year','StockID', 'QuickRef', 'sumUKQuantity', 'sumNonUKQuantity']
columns_to_use = [col for col in CSV_COLUMNS if col not in drop_columns]

columns_to_use


LABEL_COLUMN = 'totalqty'
FEATURE_COLUMNS = [column for column in columns_to_use if column != LABEL_COLUMN]
test_labels = testdf[LABEL_COLUMN]


COLUMN_DEFAULTS = [tf.dtypes.string, #ProductBrand
                  tf.dtypes.string, #Department
                  tf.dtypes.string, #ProductType
                  tf.dtypes.string, #ProductSubType
                  tf.dtypes.string, #Silo
                  tf.dtypes.string, #Level
                  tf.dtypes.string, #BaseColour
                  tf.dtypes.string, #Sport
                  tf.dtypes.string, #UKSize
                  tf.dtypes.float32, #UnitCostPrice
                  tf.dtypes.float32, #ExVatSalesValue
                  tf.dtypes.float32, #RRP_GBP
                  tf.dtypes.string, #Week
                  tf.dtypes.int32] #totalqty

def get_dataset(file_path):
    dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
        file_path,
        batch_size=60, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
        label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
        select_columns=columns_to_use ,
        column_defaults=COLUMN_DEFAULTS,
        num_epochs=1,
        ignore_errors=True,
        shuffle=False)
    return dataset

raw_train_data = get_dataset(train_file_path)
raw_test_data = get_dataset(test_file_path)


def process_categorical_data(data, categories):
    """Returns a one-hot encoded tensor representing categorical values."""

    # Remove leading ' '.
    data = tf.strings.regex_replace(data, '^ ', '')
    # Remove trailing '.'.
    data = tf.strings.regex_replace(data, r'\.$', '')

    # ONE HOT ENCODE
    # Reshape data from 1d (a list) to a 2d (a list of one-element lists)
    data = tf.reshape(data, [-1, 1])
    # For each element, create a new list of boolean values the length of categories,
    # where the truth value is element == category label
    data = tf.equal(categories, data)
    # Cast booleans to floats.
    data = tf.cast(data, tf.float32)

    # The entire encoding can fit on one line:
    # data = tf.cast(tf.equal(categories, tf.reshape(data, [-1, 1])), tf.float32)
    return data


def process_continuous_data(data, mean, std):
    # Normalize data
    data = (tf.cast(data, tf.float32) - mean) / std
    return tf.reshape(data, [-1, 1])


def preprocess(features, labels):
    # Process categorial features.
    for feature in CATEGORIES.keys():
        features[feature] = process_categorical_data(features[feature], CATEGORIES[feature])


    # Process continuous features.
    for feature in NUMERICSTATS.keys():
        features[feature] = process_continuous_data(features[feature],
                                                    NUMERICSTATS[feature]['mean'],
                                                    NUMERICSTATS[feature]['std']
                                                   )


    # Assemble features into a single tensor.
    features = tf.concat([features[column] for column in FEATURE_COLUMNS], 1)

    return features, labels


train_data = raw_train_data.map(preprocess).shuffle(len(traindf))
test_data = raw_test_data.map(preprocess)


def get_model(input_dim):
    """Create a Keras model with layers.

    Args:
        input_dim: (int) The shape of an item in a batch. 

    Returns:
        A Keras model.
    """

    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_dim,))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(244, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

    return model


input_shape, output_shape = train_data.output_shapes
input_dimension = input_shape.dims[1] # [0] is the batch size

model = get_model(input_dimension)


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)

model.compile(loss='mse',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['mae', 'mse', tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])


# The patience parameter is the amount of epochs to check for improvement
early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20)

# Display training progress by printing a single dot for each completed epoch
class PrintDot(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0: print('')
        print('.', end='')

tensor_board = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join(PARENT_DIR, 'tensorBoardLogs'))

reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                                                 factor=0.2,
                                                 patience=4,
                                                 verbose=1,
                                                 min_lr=0.00001)

history = model.fit(train_data,
                    validation_data=test_data,
                    epochs=100,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[early_stop,
                               PrintDot(),
                               tensor_board,
                               reduce_lr]
                   )


tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, saved_model_path=os.path.join(PARENT_DIR, 'models/1'))
```

What I would like is to have a model I can serve using TensorFlow serving that will take the features as they are in my training data, 13 of them and preprocess them in the model itself. Therefore using something like Flask as a middle man won't be needed

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using **`Tensorflow Transform`**, which applies the same Transformations during **`Serving`**, that you have applied during **`Training`**.

You can replace your functions, **`process_categorical_data`**, **`process_continuous_data`** and **`preprocess`** with the below code:

```
def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
    """Preprocess input columns into transformed columns."""
    x = inputs['x']
    y = inputs['y']
    s = inputs['s']
    x_centered = x - tft.mean(x)
    y_normalized = tft.scale_to_0_1(y)
    s_integerized = tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary(s)
    x_centered_times_y_normalized = (x_centered * y_normalized)
    return {
        'x_centered': x_centered,
        'y_normalized': y_normalized,
        's_integerized': s_integerized,
        'x_centered_times_y_normalized': x_centered_times_y_normalized,
    }

# Ignore the warnings
with tft_beam.Context(temp_dir=tempfile.mkdtemp()):
  transformed_dataset, transform_fn = (  # pylint: disable=unused-variable
        (raw_data, raw_data_metadata) | tft_beam.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(
            preprocessing_fn))

transformed_data, transformed_metadata = transformed_dataset  

print('\nRaw data:\n{}\n'.format(pprint.pformat(raw_data)))
print('Transformed data:\n{}'.format(pprint.pformat(transformed_data)))
```

For more details, please refer TF Transform [Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide), [Tutorial1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/transform/simple) and [Tutorial2](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/transform/census).